# Laravel using View Composer in my routes with htmlspecial error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, utf-8, laravel-5.5

I was trying to do a query in my routes for the view composer to load all the records and count it and display it in my sidebar for purposes.

I think there is no problem with the query since it worked in my shell using the php artisan tinker for testing purposes of the query.

But I got this error when I try to do it in my routes and pass it to the **menu.blade.php**

Here is the code in my routes with the view composer function.

```
// Menu View for Microbiologist
View::composer('microbiologist-dashboard.layouts.menu', function($view)
{
    $view->with('counts', [
        'microbiologist_task' => App\Models\AnalysisRequest::where('status', 'under_analyzation')
        ->whereHas('actors', function ($query) {
            $microbiologist = Auth::guard('microbiologist')->user()->id;
            $query->where('microbiologist_id', $microbiologist)->count();
        })
    ]);
});
```

and here is the code in my **menu.blade.php**

```
<span class="pull-right-container">
            @if($counts['microbiologist_task'])    
                <small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">{{ $counts['microbiologist_task'] }}</small>
            @else
            @endif
        </span>
```

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

is there something wrong with the config of my project about UTF-8? or should I use some helpers. Thanks btw I am using **Laravel 5.5**

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to display an instance of `AnalysisRequest` and not an integer. Use proper syntax:

```
$view->with('counts', [
    'microbiologist_task' => App\Models\AnalysisRequest::where('status', 'under_analyzation')
        ->whereHas('actors', function ($query) {
            $microbiologist = Auth::guard('microbiologist')->user()->id;
            $query->where('microbiologist_id', $microbiologist);
        })
        ->count();
]);
```